# Where is the leak here?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sdk

```
-(IBAction)startGameButtonClicked:(id)sender{
    //gameViewController = NULL;
    //[gameViewController release];
    //[gameViewController dealloc];

    if(!gameViewController){
        gameViewController = [[GameViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GameViewController" bundle:nil];
    }


    appDelegate.ScoreID=0;
    [gameViewController resetLevel];
    [gameViewController resetTheGame];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:gameViewController animated:YES];
} <---Says the leak is here
```

Comment: Do you release the gameViewController later on?
And are resetLevel and resetTheGame methods clean?

Answer (score 2):

set up gameViewController as a property in the .h

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) GameViewController *gameViewController;
```

and in the .m

```
@synthesize gameViewController
```

then use the property when assigning

```
self.gameViewController = [[GameViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GameViewController" bundle:nil];
```

and release at the end

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:gameViewController animated:YES];
[gameViewController release];
```

Comment: now it just highlights the last line as a leak
[gameViewController release];

Answer (score 1):

Each time the button is clicked, you make a new gameViewController and push it into self.navigationController.

You want to not make a new one each time.

Comment: Make `gameViewController` an ivar (instance variable) with properties and reference it as `self.gameViewController`.